# recursively restructure object javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, recursion, nested

So this is my method for getting all posts related to their corresponding topics.

```
const moment = require('moment');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const Post = require('../models/Post');

let posts = {
    getPosts: function(req, res) {
        return Post.find({ topicId: req.params._id })
            .then(function(result) {

                console.log('------------------------------------');
                console.log('Headed to the Client: ', result);
                console.log('------------------------------------');

                res.json(result);

            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('Nope! Nerd!');
                return Promise.reject(error);
            })
    }
}
```

the result comes out like so:

```
[ { _id: 58deac2223b5b92ce45bdfac,
    topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
    parentId: null,
    content: '1 Post',
    author: 'Bob',
    createdAt: 2017-03-31T19:21:06.698Z,
    isAnon: false,
    __v: 0,
    comments: [],
    isArchieved: false,
    isParent: true },

  { _id: 58deac2c23b5b92ce45bdfad,
    topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
    parentId: null,
    content: '2 Post',
    author: 'Bob',
    createdAt: 2017-03-31T19:21:16.622Z,
    isAnon: false,
    __v: 0,
    comments: [],
    isArchieved: false,
    isParent: true },

  { _id: 58deac3c23b5b92ce45bdfae,
    topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
    parentId: null,
    content: '3 Post',
    author: 'Bob',
    createdAt: 2017-03-31T19:21:32.682Z,
    isAnon: false,
    __v: 0,
    comments: [],
    isArchieved: false,
    isParent: true },

  { _id: 58deac5e23b5b92ce45bdfaf,
    topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
    parentId: '58deac3c23b5b92ce45bdfae',
    content: '1 Comment',
    author: 'Kat',
    createdAt: 2017-03-31T19:22:06.974Z,
    isAnon: false,
    __v: 0,
    comments: [],
    isArchieved: false,
    isParent: false },

  { _id: 58deac6c23b5b92ce45bdfb0,
    topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
    parentId: '58deac2223b5b92ce45bdfac',
    content: '2 Comment',
    author: 'Dave',
    createdAt: 2017-03-31T19:22:20.071Z,
    isAnon: false,
    __v: 0,
    comments: [],
    isArchieved: false,
    isParent: false },

 { _id: 58deac7a23b5b92ce45bdfb1,
    topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
    parentId: '58deac2c23b5b92ce45bdfad',
    content: '4 Comment',
    author: 'Bob',
    createdAt: 2017-03-31T19:22:34.865Z,
    isAnon: false,
    __v: 0,
    comments: [],
    isArchieved: false,
    isParent: false } ]
```

I am getting stuck because I need to modify this list after it comes out of the database to grab the posts with parentIds and push them into their corresponding parents'comments array.

so the the result actually sent to the client looks like this:

```
                [{
                    _id: 58deac2223b5b92ce45bdfa',
                    topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
                    parentId: null,
                    content: '1 Post',
                    author: 'Bob',
                    isAnon: false,
                    __v: 0,
                    comments: [{
                        _id: 58deac6c23b5b92ce45bdfb0,
                        topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
                        parentId: '58deac2223b5b92ce45bdfac',
                        content: '2 Comment',
                        author: 'Dave',
                        isAnon: false,
                        __v: 0,
                        comments: [],
                        isArchieved: false,
                        isParent: false
                    }],
                    isArchieved: false,
                    isParent: true
                },

                {
                    _id: 58deac2c23b5b92ce45bdfad,
                    topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
                    parentId: null,
                    content: '2 Post',
                    author: 'Bob',
                    isAnon: false,
                    __v: 0,
                    comments: [{
                        _id: 58deac7a23b5b92ce45bdfb1,
                        topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
                        parentId: '58deac2c23b5b92ce45bdfad',
                        content: '4 Comment',
                        author: 'Bob',
                        isAnon: false,
                        __v: 0,
                        comments: [],
                        isArchieved: false,
                        isParent: false
                    }],
                    isArchieved: false,
                    isParent: true
                },

                {
                    _id: 58deac3c23b5b92ce45bdfae,
                    topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
                    parentId: null,
                    content: '3 Post',
                    author: 'Bob',
                    isAnon: false,
                    __v: 0,
                    comments: [{
                        _id: 58deac5e23b5b92ce45bdfaf,
                        topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d',
                        parentId: '58deac3c23b5b92ce45bdfae',
                        content: '1 Comment',
                        author: 'Kat',
                        isAnon: false,
                        __v: 0,
                        comments: [],
                        isArchieved: false,
                        isParent: false
                    }],
                    isArchieved: false,
                    isParent: true
                }
            ]
```

I know I need to recurse through the array but I'm stumped on the logic in between. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object for collecting all nodes and append found children to the `comments` property. Get the nodes with `parentId === null` as root noded.

This approach works for unsorted data for any depth and use a single loop to get the nested result.

```js
var data = [{ _id: '58deac2223b5b92ce45bdfac', topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d', parentId: null, content: '1 Post', author: 'Bob', createdAt: '2017-03-31T19:21:06.698Z', isAnon: false, __v: 0, comments: [], isArchieved: false, isParent: true }, { _id: '58deac2c23b5b92ce45bdfad', topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d', parentId: null, content: '2 Post', author: 'Bob', createdAt: '2017-03-31T19:21:16.622Z', isAnon: false, __v: 0, comments: [], isArchieved: false, isParent: true }, { _id: '58deac3c23b5b92ce45bdfae', topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d', parentId: null, content: '3 Post', author: 'Bob', createdAt: '2017-03-31T19:21:32.682Z', isAnon: false, __v: 0, comments: [], isArchieved: false, isParent: true }, { _id: '58deac5e23b5b92ce45bdfaf', topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d', parentId: '58deac3c23b5b92ce45bdfae', content: '1 Comment', author: 'Kat', createdAt: '2017-03-31T19:22:06.974Z', isAnon: false, __v: 0, comments: [], isArchieved: false, isParent: false }, { _id: '58deac6c23b5b92ce45bdfb0', topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d', parentId: '58deac2223b5b92ce45bdfac', content: '2 Comment', author: 'Dave', createdAt: '2017-03-31T19:22:20.071Z', isAnon: false, __v: 0, comments: [], isArchieved: false, isParent: false }, { _id: '58deac7a23b5b92ce45bdfb1', topicId: '58dd6f541919c541dbf9632d', parentId: '58deac2c23b5b92ce45bdfad', content: '4 Comment', author: 'Bob', createdAt: '2017-03-31T19:22:34.865Z', isAnon: false, __v: 0, comments: [], isArchieved: false, isParent: false }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r = [],
            o = {};

        data.forEach(function (a) {
            a.comments = (o[a._id] && o[a._id].comments || []).concat();
            o[a._id] = a;
            if (a.parentId === root) {
                r.push(a);
            } else {
                o[a.parentId] = o[a.parentId] || {};
                o[a.parentId].comments = o[a.parentId].comments || [];
                o[a.parentId].comments.push(a);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, null);
    
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Awesome sauce! Thank you, however, I have a question, what if I had deeper nested objects? if comments had comments and so on? would this still be applicable?

Comment: you are actually awesome you know that? Thank you so much

Comment: Hey, Nina, I love this function but I ran into a problem wit angular and traverse :(. So I was thinking and came back to this function. Wouldn't I be able to limit the comment depth with a simple counter?

Comment: you could add a counter and exit if it reaches some limit.

Comment: But then it wouldn't have all of my comments. Haha dammit. I don't want to do that. Damn ng-repeat and it's incapability to traverse nested objects recursively. I've tried ten different solutions and none of them have worked in the slightest. Expect the one that caused an infinite loop XD. Oh well, I just have to keep searching. Thanks for help :D

Comment: sorry i can not help, because i have no clue about angular.

Comment: Maybe I just needed to vent because I literally just solved it. Yessssss